# Meaning of Rel atttibute

Tags: html, rel

I found a strange `a href` in a webpage. It looks like

```
<a href=... rel="servername.com|6d63402c" ...other properties... ></a>
```

What does  cryptic `|6d63402c mean` ? Is it a bitwise `OR` operation or just a string?

The document contains different links with different rels in this style.

Comment: See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`rel` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#attr-hyperlink-rel) specifies the link relationship type.

In HTML5 you may only use `rel` values that

- are [defined in the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes), or
- are [registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#other-link-types) in the Microformats wiki page [existing rel values: HTML5 link type extensions](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions).

As the value `servername.com|6d63402c` is not defined/registered, the page uses invalid markup.

As to what this specific value does: we can’t know (well, because it is not defined/registered). It’s probably some internal or third-party script that makes use of it. They should better use the `data-*` attribute instead of misusing `rel`.

Answer (score 1):

Per the tag wiki:
The rel attribute is used in HTML elements to specify the relationship and connection between the current document and the linked document.

Sources: *W3C* (*[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel)*)

Source: *W3Schools* (*[link](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp)*)